# comparing strings, one from an array other from an entered value

Tags: c#, string

Basically comparing a string that is entered, and trying to get that position from the array.

If I initialize position to 0 then it returns the position zero of the array, if I initialize to 1 then it gives me the item in slot 1, so it's skipping the compare statement.

I also tried using `(custStatus == cardStatus[i])`

```
public static int discount(string []cardStatus, int []pDiscount, string custStatus)
{
    int position= 0;
    int discount;
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        if (string.Equals(custStatus, cardStatus[i]))
            position = i;
    }
    discount = pDiscount[position];
    return discount;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using your debugger on this method? If you put a break point at the top on `int position= 0;` then you can confirm that `custStatus` came through as expected. Then step through to the for statement and see what happens when it tries to do the comparison.

Comment: Are you `Trim`ing your input? If your input contains a newline (or other whitespace), your string comparison will fail even if it looks like the strings match.

Answer (score 0):

This looks ok, even though this is somewhat more straightforward:

```
for(int i = 0; i < cardStatus.Length; i++)
{
    if (custStatus == cardStatus[i])
    {
        position = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Given your question it appears to be the case that all `cardStatus[i]` match `custStatus` - did you check the input?

Also given your code what happens if there is no match? Currently you would return `pDiscount[0]` - that doesn't seem to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int discount(string []cardStatus, int []pDiscount, string custStatus)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < Math.Min(cardStatus.Length, pDiscount.Length); i++)
    {
        if (string.Equals(custStatus, cardStatus[i]))
        {
            return pDiscount[i];
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Don't be afraid to return directly from FOR-loop, it is old-school that teaches to have only one return point from method. You can have as many returns as it helps you to keep your code clean and easy to read.

And perhaps it would be better to use the following expression in for-loop as it will guard you from possible different lengths of arrays:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(cardStatus.Length, pDiscount.Length; i++)
```

Comment: I don't agree with the sentence "You can have as many returns as it helps you to keep your code clean and easy to read." If the method or property is short and concise then I think it's ok to have more than one return statment. If it's a bit more laborious than that, I'd have a return value variable and return that at the end.

Comment: tried the code you guys posted,...and all of them go to the return of -1, its like it's not comparing, weird? I checked to see if the custStatus was a correct input and not being jarbbled somehow, but its ok

Comment: 2John: I've updated the answer to make sure that you scan all the array. Perhaps you have different strings, perhaps they are different in some cases (capital letters, e.t.c.), try using 3rd parameter in `Equals` set to `OrdinalIgnoreCase`.

Comment: 2Fellmeister: well, if the method if large and you can't split it to smaller ones, the introduction of some `result` variable only makes your code more dirty, you then have to pass through the method's logic and look for every situation where your result variable can be changed and assigned particular value. It's more complex then if you see `return` statement and just exit.

Answer (score 0):

With your code, there's no way to tell if `position = 0` means `custStatus` was found in your `cardStatus` array or if no match was made at all and the default value is being used. I'd recommend either using a boolean `matchFound` variable or setting `position = -1` and adding an extra if statement at the end either way. Either:

```
boolean matchFound = false;
...
if(matchFound)
{
    discount = pDiscount[position];
}
```

or else

```
int position = -1;
...
if(position >= 0)
{
    discount = pDiscount[position];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
public static int discount(string[] cardStatus, int[] pDiscount, string custStatus) {
  var position = Array.IndexOf(cardStatus, custStatus);
  return (position == -1) ? -1 : pDiscount[position];
}
```

Comment: There will be an Exception if custStatus not in cardStatus.

Comment: Updated to avoid any exceptions being thrown.